# how to zoom in/out cameraview and capture the same zoom in/out picture directly from cameraview?

Tags: iphone, ios5, avfoundation, zooming

i can capture image using avfoundation.framework as shown in [AVCam Demo](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AVCam/AVCam.zip)

but i want to

1. zoom in/out the cameraview
2. save that zoomed in/out view

i can do 1 but unable to save it in zoomed in/out mode it saved only in normal capture view

Please any one know about it help me out

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been using the following solution with success when facing similar problems:

[Capturing zoomed preview view in AVFoundation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8150148/capturing-zoomed-preview-view-in-avfoundation)